# Override Grails URL mapping from plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, url-mapping

Using Grails 2.3.11 I've run into a problem regarding dynamic URL mapping properties.
Unfortunately one of the plugins i'm depending on has a dynamic mapping for HTTP 500 status code - that is:

```
"500"('/error')
```

In my own URL mapping I wish to map this to a controller - but no matter what I do, it ignores MY URL mapping and the dynamic one from the plugin is used.

```
"500"(controller: "fejl", action: "systemfejl")
```

When running "url-mappings-report" it prints out the two mappings:

```
Dynamic Mappings
 |    *     | /${controller}/${action}?/${id}?    |     Action: (default action)  |
 |    *     | ERROR: 500                          |     View:   /error            |

Controller: fejl
 |    *     | ERROR: 403                          |     Action: ingenAdgang       |
 |    *     | ERROR: 404                          |     Action: findesIkke        |
 |    *     | ERROR: 500                          |     Action: systemfejl        |
```

The only way I can override the defined mapping from the plugin, is by defining my own "error.gsp" file and place it in the root of the "views" folder.

Is it possible in anyway to ignore urlmappings from plugins? I'm guessing this is not working as intended as URL mappings from the application should take precedent.

Comment: Maybe @burt-beckwith can elaborate? :)